# Dynamically adding text box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project for school that involve converting a form into HTML. At one point there is a drop down that asks if you are applying to be a TA or a PLA. When selected, I want a new text box to appear below that drop down. Here is what I have:

This is the dropdown data in my controller:

```
$data['selection'] = array("TA (Graduate Student)", "PLA (Undergraduate)");
```

Here is what is in the view:

```
<label for="studentSelection">What position are you applying for?
<?php echo Form::select(array( 'name'=> 'position', 'id' => 'position', 'class' => 'form-control', 'data' => $data['selection']));?>
</label>
```

This is what I'm attempting:

```
$("#position").change(function() {
//one selection is 1, the other is 0.
if ($("#position").val() == 1){  
    var row = $("<div class='row' id='row_position></div>");
    var year = $('<div class = "col-md-6"></div>');
    var position = $('<input type = "text", id="position1", name="position1" class="form-control"></input>');

    $("#position").append(row);
    row.append(year);
    year.append(position);


    //alert works when PLA is selected.
    //alert("hello");
}
else {
    //something else
}
```

I can't quite figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix the errors in your code: https://jsfiddle.net/840xyrL7/1/

```
<select id='position'>
   <option value="1">Item1</option>
   <option value="2">Item2</option>
</select>


$("#position").change(function() {
  //one selection is 1, the other is 0.
  if(this.selectedIndex === 1){
      var row = $("<div class='row' id='row" + this.selectedIndex + "'></div>");
      var year = $('<div class = "col-md-6"></div>');
      var position = $('<input placeholder="Your text" type="text" id="position' + this.selectedIndex + '"  name="position' + this.selectedIndex + '" class="form-control"></input>');
      year.append(position); 
      row.append(year);

      $("#position").after(row);

   }

});
```

Here are the lessons learned for you:

1. Do not put comma between the attributes: `type = "text", id=`
2. Be careful about closing quotes: `id='row_position></div>`
3. Do not use append if you want to add a new control next to another control: `$("#position").append(row);`, instead use `.after()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='row' id='row_position></div>
```

You're missing a closing single quote for `id`, which is probably breaking everything. Try replacing that with

```
<div class='row' id='row_position'></div>
```